# Android Programming using Eclipse and libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just updated everything libgdx, Eclipse(I'm using the Nvidia Tegra dev pack), and Android SDK. The code for my main activity won't run even though I'm almost certain it's correct. Lines of code with asterisks have errors. Help!

```
* package halberd.jc.hobo;

* import android.os.Bundle;

* import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
* import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

* public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
*    @Override
*    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific compilation errors do you see?

Comment: It'd also be useful to know which libgdx version were you working with, and which one have you updated to. Keep in mind that your question could help someone else in the future if you provide just a little more info.

Comment: I'm using the latest stable version of libgdx. It won't let me compile or run. The error message reads: "Your project contain(s) errors. Please fix them before running your application."

Comment: please be a little more specific

Comment: I just updated my sdk but whenever I open Eclipse it constantly checks for an update and I think there is one but it can't find one.

Comment: If you check the warnings/errors tab, you can expand it and see specific compilation errors.

Comment: I discovered the problem. The version of eclipse from Nvidia is buggy when checking for updates and I had to install the ADT from a .zip archive.